# Ffmpeg 2.5.2 executable not replacing existing version

Tags: 13.10, compiling, ffmpeg

I'm trying to upgrade my ffmpeg from 0.10 to the latest (2.5.2). I performed the upgrade yesterday on a different Ubuntu 13.10 machine and it worked perfectly, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I downloaded ffmpeg from [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) and followed the instructions [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) to get the dependencies, configure, and compile it. It builds without complaint and everything seems fine, however when I run ffmpeg from the command line, it still uses version 0.10.

I'd appreciate any tips on how to diagnose the problem here.

Here is the output of the commands mentioned in the comments. I ran ~/bin/ffmpeg and that is the correct version, so how would I go about running that one by default instead of the one currently being used?

echo $PATH

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

ls ~/bin

```
ffmpeg  ffplay  ffprobe  ffserver  vsyasm  yasm  ytasm
```

hash

```
hits    command
   6    /usr/bin/ffmpeg
   1    /usr/bin/ffprobe
   6    /usr/bin/sudo
  14    /bin/ls
   1    /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

Comment: Please show the output of `echo $PATH`, `ls ~/bin`, and `hash`. Are you using the same user account that you used to compile?

Comment: I am using the same account (well, I used sudo on the make command, not sure if that counts as a different user). I found that ~/bin/ffmpeg is the correct version - not sure how to make it run by default though.

Comment: Try running `. ~/.profile`, then `hash -r`, then `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Dumb question: have you tried `locate --regexp "^\(.*/\)*ffmpeg$"` ?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - That did it, thank you! Would you mind explaining why that worked? Also, it only switches it for the current terminal session - can it be made permanent?

Comment: If you log out of your current desktop environment session and then log in is the behavior persistent?

Comment: It isn't, every time I open the terminal it stays the same. I've added my local bin directory to $PATH in my .bashrc file, which seems to get the job done.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was not persistent for you. Also, I don't know why `~/bin` doesn't seem to be in the `$PATH` by default since it's already in `~/.profile` last I checked, but that was a while ago since I'm not personally using Ubuntu. Anyway, if you found a solution you can provide it as an answer.